# SQL Date Time Format Discrepancy

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a bit of a problem. I am trying to import a SQL file into SOLR, except SOLR wants the datetime in the following format:

```
1995-12-31T23:59:59Z
```

But using datetime in SQL I can only have it in this format:

```
1995-12-31 23:59:59
```

If I put the date in a varchar field then I will lose the ability to do date based calculations on the SQL file. So, my question is, can I somehow get SQL to accept the datetime in the solr (first) format?

Answer (score 0):

This conversion will be done automatically by SOLR if you use the standard DateTime type for you your field, something like this :

```
<field name="from_date" type="datetime" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

If it still doesn't work, convert your date using this :

```
DateTimeFieldSerializer date = new DateTimeFieldSerializer();
string fromDate = date.SerializeDate(myDate);
```